# Is "continue" bad practice?

Tags: python

Is using `continue` in Python considered bad practice? It seems like stopping a function/etc mid-execution is a generally "poor" way to construct a program, like `sys.exit()` under the wrong circumstances, or `goto`.

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world/216375#216375

Answer (score 3):

The basis of structured programming is to have well defined entry and exit points into a method - ideally one of each. However, this isn't a hard and fast rule, and there are many cases where it is appropriate to have multiple exit points. I would say have a look at the code, think about whether there's a different way to do it without a 'continue' that is still elegant, and if not, using the 'continue' will be the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use of flow control is a controversial subject.

One school of thought believes that they obscure the code, by hiding the flow control a reader would assume -- a linear one.

Another school of thought thinks that they are justifiable if the alternative is complicated logic (like additional flags and more complex loop conditions).

Your best bet is to look at your code and decide; would using anything like continue hide the flow control?  Can your code be expressed cleanly without it?

My opinion is this: if you have no compelling reason to do otherwise, I recommend you avoid continue and its kin.

Comment: `As an example, think of a case in a loop where an early exit is needed. Without a control flow break, you'd have to do things with flag variables in your loop, which can complicate your loop.` I can't think of any cases where I would use break other than such an instance. Likewise, I can't think of any places I would use continue unless I want to end my current iteration of the loop, and start the next. Those cases are precisely why continue and break exist.

Comment: Sure, but they can (and are) abused; I've seen code that runs an infinite loop where the loop control is in the body, courtesy of a flow control break.  I've also seen cases in which a loop with logic that's easily expressed with an if-statement within a loop relies on a negative test and continue.

Comment: Yes, of course they can be abused, just about everything can be abused. That doesn't mean they should be avoided altogether (which is what your first sentence says: `Generally speaking, any kind of code that could cause a "break" in flow control is considered bad practice`)

Comment: I didn't say that; if I did, I wouldn't have used "generally", nor would I have explicitly presented the other school of thought along with situations that could justify the use -- situations you agreed with.  Generally is not an absolute term.

Comment: Even though this post is closed, I adjusted my answer.  Perhaps it's all in the presentation.

Comment: Interesting, even though you've deleted your answer and the question itself has been closed I can still see your answer (although it is greyed-out).

Answer (score 0):

Using continue in Python, personally, is fine. If you're putting it in a if/else statement type condition in python, continue will work.